# Why whenever i put <?php include_once('admin_nav.html'); ?> it shows Confirm Form Resubmission?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Everything's fine and I found a helpful way to prevent page from Confirm Form Resubmission when I added reloaded the page however, whenever I tried to put the  at the top, inside the body tag - the Confirm Form Resubmission shows again if I hit reload. I am confused cause I am just placing the menu with include then all of a sudden it would duplicate things that has already been submitted to database. Any help to clear the confusion would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

this is the include for the menu

```
<?php include_once('admin_nav.html'); ?>
```

This code stops duplication whenever reload button is clicked. I got this somewhere on the internet and to whoever I got this, thank you!

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $_SESSION['postdata'] = $_POST;
    unset($_POST);
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Never copy paste the code that you don't understand. You never know about it's side effects.

Comment: That code looks like a partially implemented PRG pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). But I don't understand your question. Please rephrase it.

Comment: And to answer your question, you should break the code in pieces and read about each function/global var one by one. It's fairly simple why it is happening but you will need to read about it.

Comment: Sorry for that and thanks. I would do your suggestions. I'll check further to understand the codes line by line.

Comment: You need to edit your question so you're asking for what you actually need. You can further check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think your questions is, "I've copied/pasted this code which is supposed to stop duplicate form submissions." Is that right? If so, then you need to show us the HTML for the form that is being submitted; I suspect it is using GET and your code is looking for POST. In addition, that code should be at the *very top* of the page since it issues a header command. Put it before anything that outputs content.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ That `unset($_POST);` is pointless in that context since you're about to redirect the user anyway.